# Can't read table from a pdf file using matplotlib.pyplot - Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, ansible

I have a python script which is called from a loop via ansible. The idea is to create a table (in the first iteration) using matplotlib library and modify the same table at each iteration.
I want to modify the same table at each loop, so at the first loop creation_of_table is true, after the first iteration, creation_of_table is set to false. When creation_of_table is set to False, I don't know how to read the created table in a pdf from the first loop, so I can always modify the same table. Can someone help me with this . I would really appreciate it

I have the `script.py` that looks like this :

`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

val1 = ["ABC", "DEC", "IFG", "HTI", "CBF", "JSF", "FHYU", "FJu", "JSF", "JSF", "JSF", "JSF", "SMQ1", "SMQ2", "JSF", "JSF", "SMU", "PYTHON", "JAVA", "TDS", "JFSF", "F", "HUN", "R"]
val2 = ["ROOM", "OIT", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "","", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
val3 = [["" for c in range(24)] for r in range(24)] 

def cration_tableau():
    creation_of_table = True
    fig, ax = plt.subplots() 
    ax.set_axis_off() 
    table = ax.table( 
        cellText = val3,  
        rowLabels = val2,  
        colLabels = val1, 
        rowColours = ["palegreen"] * 24,  
        colColours = ["palegreen"] * 24, 
        cellColours = [["grey"] * 24] * 24,
        cellLoc ='center',  
        loc ='upper left') 
    ax.set_title('TBAL', fontweight ="bold") 
    return table

def color_table(table, color, number_cell):
    number_cell = int(number_cell)
    table[(number_cell, 14)].set_facecolor(color)

def pdf_conversion():   
    plt.show()
    plt.savefig('test.pdf') 

def main(color, number_cell, creation_of_table):
    if creation_of_table is True:
        table = cration_tableau()
    else:
       #Don't know how to read the created pdf

    color_table(table, color, number_cell)
    pdf_conversion()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    color = sys.argv[1]
    number_cell = sys.argv[2]
    creation_of_table = sys.argv[3]
    main(color, number_cell, creation_of_table)
```

`

The ansible task that is called within a loop:

```
- name: Execution of the script
   ansible.builtin.command: python3.6 script.py "black" "{{ number_cell }}" "{{ creation_of_table }}"
```